# How to format date to mmddyyhrmin in sybase

Tags: sybase

i want the date format in mmddyyhhmin . Can anyone help me in achieving this.
for eg : FOR GETDATE RESULT SHOULD BE "032520130550"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select str_replace(convert(varchar,getdate(),101),'/',null)+str_replace(convert(char(5),getdate(),108),':',null)
```